# How to develop stack overflow like notification system

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, notifications, signalr

stack over site has nice notification system. when we post any question and stick to that page and in the mean time if anyone give answer or post any comment or edit my question or else question then a notification message comes where we click and data load.

### here is image

[image]

1) this kind of notification can be developed by signalR

2) we can write JQuery function which will run every section in background and hit the server to check if any answer arrived for the question or not  or check any existing question change or not or check any comments comes or not etc if any activity found then a message shown on page to request user to load the change.

but i have no idea how stack overflow developed this notification system ?
so i am looking for best guidance to develop similar kind of notification system for any site.

thanks

### EDIT

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.sendMessage(name,message);
    }
}

code in global.asax
protected void Application_Start(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
}

client code

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Proxy created on the fly          
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));

        // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it          
        chat.client.sendMessage = function (name, message) {
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            $('#messages').append('<li>' + encodedName + 
                ':  ' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $("#send").click(function () {
                // Call the chat method on the server
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#msg').val());
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

hi @Anders thanks for your guidance and you asked me to use your library but when i go to that page i found no solid code which i need to put in my page. generally when we work with signalr then we wrote the above code. one side hub and another side is client but i do not understand what i need to write to implement your code and also i like to know what more your code will provide.

so please guide me in detail. thanks

Comment: running jquery  to hit server every second will not be good idea  for every section.

Comment: so guide me in details what would be best approach?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is easy, using pub/sub to push the updates to the clients. In reality it takes time to develop such a feature rich and real time CMS. Start easy and add features as you go.

Do not poll, use SignalR instead, my quess is that Stackoverflow uses some kind of CQRS domain. In the read model store you can push changes to the message bus and then forward them to the clients.

You can check my Event aggregator proxy for signalR,

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

On the client I would use Knockout or SignalR, but keep in mind that if you want SEO to work you need to render the content on server too

Comment: you are right that we can use signalr to push the changes to pages.  i know signalr but do not know how to use this as per my requirement that when anyone give answer for the question then a notification will go to all other user on that page. it would be help if you please explain in detail how to broad cast the notification to everyone on that page. thanks

Comment: If you use my lib you can add a constraint then the listener will only get updates for that specific entity,https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki/Implement-constraint-handlers

Comment: If you decide to go with vanilla signalr then you can develop something similar yourself

Comment: Please see the demo for how to use this both to publish from server and listen on client. https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4